# How to update a foreign key field which is actually a duplicate in its parent with unique id?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl, dml

I have a `Widget` table with fields as `[id(primary key), label}`. This table somehow as duplicate `label` field shown below.

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | label    |
+-----+----------+
| 01  | Customer |
| 02  | Client   |
| 03  | Customer |
| 04  | Customer |
| 05  | Customer |
| 06  | Client   |
| 07  | Client   |
+-----+----------+
```

There is another table called `company` having `label_id` as foreign key. The foreign key can be null.

```
+-----+------+----------+
| id  | name | label_id |
+-----+------+----------+
| 400 | ABC  | 01       |
| 401 | DEF  | 02       |
| 402 | ADF  | 06       |
| 403 | QWE  | 05       |
| 404 | RST  | 06       |
| 405 | WAS  | null     |
+-----+------+----------+
```

Since `label_id` `06` and `05` are duplicate as they point to same `Customer` and `Client` label. I need to reassign them to id 01 and 02 and every other records with such duplicate label_ids . After that remove all the duplicate records in `Widget` table.

```
Note :`CASCADE on DELETE` referential action is not applied in my table.
```

Need suggestion on how to do this ??

Comment: How you have `06` twice in widget if that is primary key? Also I don't see where `05` is duplicated.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I have corrected that typo. `05` is duplicate as its corresponding `label` value is `Customer`. So instead of `05` it has to updated to `01`. After all those re-mapping , I need to remove all those `Customer` and `Client` duplicate records in `Widget` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your requirment but maybe something like this

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50c1f7/1)**

```
UPDATE Company C
SET 
`label_id` =  (SELECT MIN(`id`)
               FROM  Widget
               WHERE `label` = (SELECT `label` 
                                FROM Widget W 
                                WHERE W.`id` = C.`label_id`)
              );
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|  id | name | label_id |
|-----|------|----------|
| 400 |  ABC |        1 |
| 401 |  DEF |        2 |
| 402 |  ADF |        2 |
| 403 |  QWE |        1 |
| 404 |  RST |        2 |
| 405 |  WAS |   (null) |
```